# Determine $m$ such that $\psi_m:\overline{x}\in\mathbb Z_{16} \to \overline{m}\overline{x} \in \mathbb Z_{16}$ is a bijection etc

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Determine $m \in \mathbb Z$ such that $\psi_m:\overline{x}\in\mathbb Z_{16} \to \overline{m}\overline{x} \in \mathbb Z_{16}$ is a bijection. Let $T$ be the set of such $m$ elements, if $m \in T$ is it true that $5m \in T$? Is $T$ a closed structure in $(\mathbb Z, +)$ and/or $(\mathbb Z, \cdot)$?

In order for $\psi_m$ to be a bijection, then $\overline{m}$ has to be an invertible element in $\mathbb Z_{16}$, therefore $\gcd(\overline{m}, 16) = 1$. Moreover if $\gcd(\overline{m}, 16) = 1$, so $\overline{m}$ and $16$ are relatively prime numbers, then $\overline{5}\overline{m}$ and $16$ are relatively prime.

I would say that $T$ is the following set:

$T = \{0 + 16\mathbb Z\} \cup\{1 + 16\mathbb Z\} \cup\{3 + 16\mathbb Z\} \cup\{5 + 16\mathbb Z\} \cup\{7 + 16\mathbb Z\} \cup\{9 + 16\mathbb Z\} \cup\{11 + 16\mathbb Z\} \cup\{13 + 16\mathbb Z\}\cup\{15 + 16\mathbb Z\}$

Let $m_1, m_2 \in T$, in particular $m_1 = 3 \in \{3+16\mathbb Z\}$ and $m_2 = 1 \in \{1+16\mathbb Z\}$, then $m_1+m_2=3+1=4 \not\in T$, so $T$ isn't closed in $(\mathbb Z, +)$. Conversely $\forall m_1, m_2 \in T, m_1 \cdot m_2 = m \in T$, because, as claimed before, multiplying two relatively prime numbers to $16$, you get another relatively prime number to $16$ so $T$ is actually closed in $(\mathbb Z, \cdot)$.

Is my answer right? Have I got anything wrong? Is there something that could be improved?

Comment: $\{0 + 16\mathbb Z\}\not\in T$. You can something improve: $T=\{ \{k+ 16\mathbb Z\}\mid 1\le k\le 15, k\ {\rm is \ odd}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicely argued:

But caution: $\{0 + 16\mathbb Z\} \notin T$, since $\gcd{0, 16} = 16 \neq 1$.

Also, note that $\bar{m}$ are odd integers between $1$ and $15$, so you can abbreviate your definition of $T$ as follows: $$\large T = \bigcup_{1 \leq k \leq 15, k \text{ is odd}} k + 16\mathbb Z,$$ or as Boris suggested: $$T = \{\{k + 16 \mathbb Z\}\mid 1 \leq k \leq 15, k\; \text{is odd}\}$$

Comment: :^D......${}{}{}$